# Does clock_gettime() work if clock_settime has not been set?

Tags: c++, c, linux, time, real-time-clock

Does clock_gettime() work if the clock has NOT been set by clock_settime()? I have a situation where repeated calls to clock_gettime() returns the same time value (seconds). I seem to remember that I needed to first set the time with clock_settime(). Also do clock_gettime() and time()  use the same time source?

```
clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp) - All  implementations  support  the system-wide real-time clock, which is identified by CLOCK_REALTIME.  Its time represents seconds and nanoseconds SINCE THE EPOCH.  When its time is changed, timers for a  relative  interval  are  unaffected,  but timers for an absolute point in time are affected.

time() - returns the time as the number of seconds SINCE THE EPOCH, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).
```

Code is C, platform is Ubuntu 18.04. C++ is tagged in this question, because as far as I know C++ does not provide an method of obtaining high precision time (though C++20 does), and I will create a C++ version of my code.

Comment: Are you checking it's return value for errors and handling appropriately, or just assuming it works?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: What is the code you are using? Also, read `man 3 clock_gettime`.

Comment: What do you mean by "return the same value"? do they fill the same values in the `struct timespec*` argument? `clock_gettime(2)` only returns 0 or -1 for an error. Passing a NULL pointer for the `struct timespec*` argument is not an error.

Comment: @sjsam I do not think most C++ versions support fine-grained time. I am using this function in a C++ application. I know C++ 20 supports fine-grained time. From an pedantic perspective, yes this is not a C++ question, and I would not post it on comp.lang.c++ :D

Comment: @xofo, The question is incomplete as it doesn't show any code.  It could be that the return value indicates an error.  `clk_id` could be referencing a clock that has a low resolution and `tp` isn't updating because it is being checked to often.  Also you mention the seconds isn't updating or is it that every field of `tp` is identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clock_settime` sets the time for the entire computer.  Only system administration tools (e.g. the [GNOME Control Center](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center)) and time synchronization daemons (e.g. [ntpd](http://www.ntp.org/)) should ever need to call it.  It requires superuser privileges; most programs *cannot* successfully call it.

If `clock_settime` (or one of the older APIs that do the same job) has never been called on a particular computer, the values returned by `clock_gettime` may well be *wrong* by comparison to some authoritative source of the current time.  However, the clocks should all still be *running*, whether or not the time is accurate.  I'm not aware of any API, on Linux or otherwise, to *stop* the system clock.

However however, depending which clock ID you're using, getting the same value from two consecutive calls to `clock_gettime` may be normal (not a bug or a problem).  For instance, this may happen if the interval between the two calls is shorter than the resolution of the clock, as reported by `clock_getres`.

Comment: This is the answer - Time must first be set on the host computer. Question - Do time and clock_gettime use the SAME clock (time source)?

Comment: @Xofo I think you misunderstood the answer. What I am saying is that `clock_gettime` should produce times that advance _whether or not_ the time has already been set (but watch out for the resolution).  Please don't ask new questions in the comments on answers; post another question instead.

Comment: I understood your answer, and you answered my question. Time must FIRST be set. getimeofday is deprecated though.

Comment: I don't understand how you got from "clock_gettime should produce times that advance __whether or not__ the time has already been set" to "time must __first__ be set".

Comment: My question was answered very well by you - Time must first be set . "clock_settime sets the time for the entire computer" ... someone has to set it, and this resolved the behavior I was seeing.

Comment: @Xofo Time does not need to be set via `clock_settime()` for `clock_gettime()` to return a valid `tp`.  It just may be the wrong time in comparison to the actual local time.  For example an embedded Linux system with no network access and no real-time clock to set an initial clock time.

Comment: @Xofo If you observed that successive calls to `clock_gettime` were returning the same value, and then you called `clock_settime`, and then you observed that  successive calls to `clock_gettime` were returning different values, then either you were using some operating system very different from Unix/Linux/Posix, or you were using some clkid very different from CLOCK_REALTIME, because basically, what you observed is impossible.